# How to disable row shifting when column is sorting in datatable

Tags: vb.net, winforms, sorting, datatable, datagridview

[image]
hi

When it is sorted, when I give a value to the cell, the row moves. I don't want this to happen. I work with DataGridView and DataTable

```
    Dim MyDataTable As New DataTable
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            MyDataTable.Columns.Add("id")
    MyDataTable.Columns.Add("f1")
    MyDataTable.Columns.Add("f2")
    MyDataTable.Columns.Add("f3")
    MyDataTable.Rows.Add({"1", "a1", "b1", "c1"})
    MyDataTable.Rows.Add({"2", "a2", "b2", "c2"})
    MyDataTable.Rows.Add({"3", "a3", "b3", "c3"})
    dgv.DataSource = MyDataTable
    dgv.Columns(0).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Programmatic
    dgv.Columns(1).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Programmatic
    dgv.Columns(2).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Programmatic
    dgv.Columns(3).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Programmatic
End Sub

 Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    MyDataTable.DefaultView.Sort = "[f2] asc"
End Sub
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve here? You'd barely even notice an array of 100 `Integers` being created so this example doesn't really demonstrate anything useful.  What are you actually doing that you think is too slow and how exactly did you determine that it's too slow. Simplified examples to demonstrate a principle are good but if they don't demonstrate anything useful then we can't really know whether we're helping with regard to the real scenario.

Comment: These days, if you really want to process in parallel then you would use Tasks and let the system worry about the implementation details. You might have a method or lambda expression that took a start index and count and then invoke it multiple times. Having multiple methods that basically do the same thing is not the best way to do anything.

Comment: The symbolic 100 is an example. After the answer, 999999999 will be replaced by 100. Now I want to know the more precise method with a simple example.

Comment: @MansourDalir Maybe [How to: Write a Simple Parallel.For Loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-for-loop) would be of interest to you. Do remember to compare it to a single loop, as that can be faster depending on the number of iterations.

Comment: Hello. I still need to be limited? I can't ask questions.

Comment: Someone take me out of the limit. Where should I say this? Introduce a link to remove the restriction. I can't ask.

Comment: Someone take me out of the limit. Where should I say this? Introduce a link to remove the restriction. I can't ask.